# Asus X99 Pro Bluetooth - Ubuntu Mate 17.10

Tags: bluetooth, 17.10, asus

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate 17.10 and all works great except for my bluetooth. It seems to work but cannot find any bluetooth device. If I add a USB bluetooth dongle it can find devices properly.
Computer has a motherboard ASUS X99 PRO/USB3.1. with on board wifi/bluetooth. Wifi and Network works properly.

I was looking at the questions and answers to similar questions and came across the answer for question 585251. The answer did not work for me as I asume the answer was specific to 14.04.

Controller information from my computer

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1043:855c]
```

lsusb gives

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 06f8:3014 Guillemot Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 05e3:0745 Genesys Logic, Inc. Logilink CR0012
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0b05:17cf ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If I use `hciconfig --all` it provides the following info:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 30:10:B3:9C:CB:6B  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:1094 acl:0 sco:0 events:70 errors:0
    TX bytes:5189 acl:0 sco:0 commands:70 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'john-X99-Mate'
    Class: 0x1c0104
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x1000
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x220e
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

Would be great if anybody has a solution for my problem?